# How to run macro without open Excel

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I tried to execute a .vbs script to run macro inside Excel without opening the workbook.
but when I open the workbook I found that nothing changed.

macro for changing column type from text to number percentage.

```
Public Sub updateColumnFormat()

    'Disable screen update and calculation to improve the performance of import
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.EnableCancelKey = True
    Application.Calculation = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Sheets("Status").Select
    [B:B].Select 'Update data type from text to number of CreditLimit (Column B)
    With Selection
      .NumberFormat = "General"
      .Value = .Value
    End With
    Selection.Style = "Percent"
    Call Refreashstage
    'Sheets("Status").Select
    'Range("B3").Select
    'Sheets("Sales").Select
    On Error Resume Next

End Sub

Sub Refreashstage()

    Sheets("Status").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    Sheets("FY21 Sales Forecast").Select

End Sub
```

.vbs script to execute macro without open the Excel

```
Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Run "'C:\Users\NB\Desktop\test6.xlsm'!Module1.updateColumnFormat"
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: I just tested it. running a script from currently unopened workbook just automatically triggers the workbook to open. When you do `objExcel.Application.Run` you're opening the workbook in the hidden excel application that you created. When you do `objExcel.Application.Quit`, you're closing the workbook after opening it.

Comment: @Toddleson, Yes when I run the .vbs script I found the hidden file(~$test6) like when I open the excel. and after finished the hidden file was gone because `objExcel.Application.Quit` right? but when I open the workbook for check I found that the result doesn't change and the file modified date also doesn't change. So what should I do to call macro to take effect?

Comment: You need to actually save the workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a script from currently unopened workbook automatically triggers the workbook to open. When you do `objExcel.Application.Run` you're opening the workbook in the hidden excel application that you created. If you were to insert the line `objExcel.Visible = True` after the `.Run` line, you would see the open workbook.

When you do `objExcel.Application.Quit`, you're closing the workbook after opening it. And the line `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` disabled the pop-up that would've asked if you wanted to save the changes made to the workbook before closing. It defaults to "No" and discards all changes.

Close the workbook properly before doing `objExcel.Quit` with:

VBA:`objExcel.Workbooks(1).Close SaveChanges:=True`

VBScript: `objExcel.Workbooks(1).Close True`

Side Note: Your code uses `.Select` in very unnecessary ways. `.Select` is only really useful for drawing the user's attention towards screen regions or cells. But your workbook is not even visible, so `.Select` is only slowing down execution and making object references ambiguous.

I would suggest your code be improved to something like:

```vb
    'Update data type from text to number of CreditLimit (Column B)
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Status").Columns("B")
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
        .Style = "Percent"
    End With
    Call Refreashstage
```

Comment: Dear@Toddleson That’s very kind of you, but I tried to add `savechanges:=True` in the .vbs script like this 
`objExcel.Workbooks("C:\Users\NB\Desktop\test6.xlsm").Close Savechanges:=True`  
before line `objExcel.Application.Quit`

it show error about `Error : Expected statement Code 800A0400`

Comment: @alice the workbook name you have entered is not correct. Just use `objExcel.Workbooks(1)` as I wrote in my answer. There is only one workbook open in the application, so `.Workbooks(1)` will reference the correct workbook.

Comment: I tried to used `objExcel.Workbooks(1).close savechanges:=True` but found the same error again. That error tell about that line at Char:41 that is the character position at `=` after that I tried to used `=` instead of `:=` it run finish but didn't save anything T^T

Comment: Dear @Toddleson Wow, it works!! I used this `.Close True`. I really appreciate for your help

Comment: The problem is VBScript doesn’t understand named parameter arguments like `SaveChanges:=` that is VBA syntax.